# Does the Realta Nua PC Releases still have the route branch in the Fate Route

Tags: fate-stay-night

i know that the Realta Nua PC version was released as 3 games and there is now a patch for all 3 (i'm waiting abit before i get it just to allow the bugs to get ironed out) however one thing got to me,

in the Original PC version you had to complete the Fate Route in order to trigger the flag at the end to allow for the possibility of accessing the Unlimited Blade Works Route (which doesn't lead to Shirou creating a Geis with Rin and thus a Dead End) and it was the same with Heaven's Feel, you needed to trigger a flag from completing one Unlimited Blade Works Route in order to access an option to gain an extra affection point with Sakura in order to access the Heaven's Feel Route (all of this is based off Mirror Moon's Flowchart provided with the patch install), and ofcause -Last Episode- was only ever unlocked unless all 5 endings had been seen (needed a separate patch to add it though)

however, from what i have seen, all 3 routes are separate games with separate .exe files, so i am wondering, does the Realta Nua PC Releases still have the route branch in the Fate Route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each game is each route with all possible bad ending self contained, this means rather than having to play Fate and Unlimited Blade Works before playing Heaven's Feel one can just play Heaven's Feel without ever seeing Fate's ending.

Since they are self contained, Rin's Prologue of the first 3 days before Archer is attacked by Saber after they chase Lancer to the Emiya Compound and the portion of the Fate Route which is common to all 3 is included, also the Unlimited Blade Works Bad End one can obtain in Fate before getting it's completion Flag is also included in Fate.

However, *-Last Episode-* and the *Tiger Dojo Completion Ceremony* requires all 3 games and it seems data is shared between them, a sneaky tactic by TYPE-MOON to get people to buy all 3 (Tiger Dojo Completion Ceremony is one thing but -Last Episode- is like the proper conclusion to Fate)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they still have the route branch but they change some scenes and improve the quality of CGs... Realta Nua also adds the canon epilogue written by Nasu "last episode"

Last episode was written by Nasu as a final epilogue once the game is finished.

"Last episode" can happen in different timelines/routes but it is sure to happen after Fate's true ending. The reason is that it is done as an epilogue for such ending (it actually says epilogue).

Nasu has made epilogues for all 3 true endings. In the original game he did Heaven's Feel true ending epilogue. After some time he did Fate's true ending epilogue "last episode" and recently he's made UBW's true ending epilogue (an 11 page script that was handed to Ufotable in order to make the epilogue episode). All 3 epilogues are sure to happen after each true ending.
"Last episode" can also happen in other timelines though.

Comment: The first paragraph of this is just repeating what the accepted answer said, and the rest is not pertinent to the question being asked.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer In my opinion it is pertinent. Realta Nua has a bigger budget and changes some scenes as I said. After that I don't repeat what Memor said regarding how to access the routes as it's already said. Memor is asking about the game branches and "last episode". Knowing the relation between these is something I believe readers will want to know as it is relevant imho to emphasize that even though Realta Nua allows you to play any route at any time they are not self-sufficient and need the rest of the material written by Nasu to fully understand them.

Comment: No, how to see the epilogues does not answer the question being asked. Maybe read the question again.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I know that XD. The main point is to emphasize that Realta Nua lets the player play the game in any order but the routes are not self-suffient, they complement each other and "last episode" is an epilogue at the end of the game for a reason. I referenced the other 2 epilogues for a better understanding, that's all. But I get your point as well so let's end the discussion.

Comment: To add something to my answer I want to say that even though it is as Memor says in his question " from what i have seen, all 3 routes are separate games with separate .exe files" I strongly advise to play the game in the way the previous version intended (Fate then UBW then HF). The reason is that the Fate route explains the mechanics of the game and the game keeps telling us new details after each route that actually spoil previous routes. Maintaining this order is the best option unless you want to skip a route (for example UBW since the anime adapatation is very faithful).

Comment: You should comment on the answer if you're just commenting on an answer.

Comment: I'm leaving it as a comment because I feel like It's more like an addon if someone wants to read the comments XD But thank you^^

Comment: ...that's exactly what I said. I can see why you answered with something completely unrelated, though.

Comment: Ohh, sorry I thought you were telling me to edit my answer to add that detail.

Comment: Anyways, I put it as a comment to my own answer because I think it is linked to our previous discussion in the comments section. Thank you very much for all your tips :)